# VueJs emit('input') firing 2 values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component which has an input so to use v-model I use this

```
<template>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="value"
      :id="inputId"
      placeholder=""
      @input="updateText"
    />
    <label :for="inputId">{{ label }}</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
export default {
  name: "InputField",
  props: {
    value: { type: String },
    inputId: { type: String },
    label: { type: String },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const value = ref("");
    const updateText = () => {
      emit("input", value.value);
    };
    return {
      value,
      updateText,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="less" scoped>
</style>
```

So when I console so I used the v-model in the parent component but the value is not changing so I tried to print the @input data .. It returns 2 values.. The value of the input and the ref object

```
<div class="login-box">
    <InputField
        v-model="username"
        label="Username "
        inputId="username"
        @input="printUser"
    />
    <input type="text" />
<div>{{ username }}</div>
```

Any help.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In vue 3 `v-model` on a component is syntactic sugar for

```
<input-field
  :model-value="username"
  @update:model-value="username = $event"
></input-field>
```

so you're input field component should be

```
<template>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      type="text"
      :value="modelValue"
      :id="inputId"
      placeholder=""
      @input="updateText"
    />
    <label :for="inputId">{{ label }}</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
export default {
  name: "InputField",
  props: {
    ...
    modelValue: { type: String },
    ...
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const updateText = (e) => {
      emit("update:modelValue", e.target.value);
    };
    return {
      updateText,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.. The v-model in the parent component is still empty. And I used this same thing in the question before it worked correctly but not in this project..